# Do i need to startManagingCursor when using changeCursor?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using my own CursorAdapter to populate a Listview from a sqlite db. An AsyncTask periodically (and on user Request) fetches new Data from the web and writes it to db.

To redisplay the fresh data, i set the adapters cursor to a newly created Cursor using [changeCursor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29).

```java
Cursor allCities = mCityTableHelper.fetchAll();
startManagingCursor(allCities);
mCityAdapter.changeCursor(allCities);
```

But: Do i **have** to "startManagingCursor()" all the time? Or can i create new Cursors at will and rely on changeCursor() to close them again?  I'm curious as this might get called often during the apps lifetime. Besides "startManagingCursor" is deprecated in favor of CursorLoad. Which sadly is not an Option as i need API Level 7.

Comment: Now that i have alot of different temporary Cursors after some time i hit **IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@** 

So I'm thinking of just having one cursor, and manually managing it with the Activities LifeCycle and requery() as needed. But, as i know these functions are all deprecated i feel awkward going this way.

Comment: Hm ...  so i made the Cursors members of the Activity and requery() them as needed. Though this Code seems deprecated, i guess its the only valid option in pre 3.0.